# Maven Module Project not found

Tags: java, maven, module

I've a multi module maven project. I'm trying to access the content of a module from another module. Maven gives me this error.

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project net.twerion:wrapper:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.twerion:cloud.packets:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.twerion:cloud.packets:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.twerion:cloud:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The Module wrapper is the compiled module, packets the accessable module and cloud the project.

Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>cloud</artifactId>
    <groupId>net.twerion</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>wrapper</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.twerion</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloud.packets</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>net.twerion.wrapper.MainClass</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>io.netty:*</include>
                        <include>net.twerion:cloud.packets</include>
                        <include>org.eclipse.jetty:*</include>
                        <include>javax.servlet:*</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>io.netty:*</artifact>
                    </filter>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>org.eclipse.jetty:*</artifact>
                    </filter>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>javax.servlet:*</artifact>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

packets pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>cloud</artifactId>
    <groupId>net.twerion</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>packets</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Which Pom? The Porject or module pom?

Comment: the both, but pay attention if there are some sensitive data please clean up them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first pom references the wrong artefact id. Instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.twerion</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloud.packets</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

you should be using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.twerion</groupId>
    <artifactId>packets</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Then it should work.